# Prism: EventAggregator prevents WPF application from closing

Tags: wpf, prism, eventaggregator

I am using the Microsoft.Practices.Prism.PubSubEvents.IEventAggregator default implementation to wire up view models to respond to the application closing event as follows:

```
public class MainViewModel
{

     public MainViewModel( IEventAggregator eventAggregator, Shell shell)
     {
        _shell.Closing += OnApplicationClosing;
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

   private void OnApplicationClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {           
            //TODO: investigate why this is locking application.
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ApplicationClosingEvent>().Publish(new CancelEventArgs());           
        }
}
```

When I wire this event, application hangs upon closing.  WPF Application is using .NET 4.5 and Prism v5.0.0.0 with Prism.PubSubEvents 1.0.0.0

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Could it be that one of rhe subscribers  has long synchrouness operations when handling this event synchroniosly

Comment: Very likely, since when I comment out the subscription code, application shuts down ok.  Apparently a problem with my architecture.

Comment: Couldn't these long running operations , be done on background threads ?

Comment: There are no long running operations.  Problem turns out to be a null exception being thrown when attempting to access a Dictionary<string, object> with a null key by one of the event subscribers. This caused the crash.  Thx again.

Comment: You should delete the question. As it seems to be irrelevant